# Is there a way to disable/edit the fading that a list view has at its edges?

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, fade, scrollview

Scrollable views such as the ListView have a fade out of the content along the edges where there is more content in that direction.  How can I turn this fading off?  I know you can change the cacheColorHint as discussed here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html but that is not what I am looking for and will not achieve what I am looking for in this case.

I want to disable the fade completely or be able to reduce the size and or transparency of it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I can't actually test it right now, but I believe fadingEdge is what you're looking for:

`android:fadingEdge="none"`

or

`listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(boolean)

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.  Also, I see there is a field called android:fadingEdgeLength for controlling the length of the fade.  Thanks again.

Comment: It should be noted that fadingedges is disabled per default for all scrollviews from ice cream sandwich and henceforth (http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/19/curiosities-ice-cream-sandwich.html)

Comment: Heh, funny that this answer comes back to help ME. Thanks @Warpzit, I was actually wondering yesterday why my fading edge wasn't working on ICS. :)

Comment: @kcoppock heh well I figured it out because I was wondering why fadingedge was deprecated :) Glad it already helped someone :D

Answer (score 49):

In case someone finds this via Google:

As mentioned, `android:fadingEdge` is deprecated. Use this instead:

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me on 4.3. All the suggestions above simply don't work.

Comment: If i need disable fadingEdge but without disabling OverScroll?

Comment: this solution should be accepted , its the preferred way to do it.

Comment: Works for RecyclerView too, tested

Answer (score 9):

Late answer, but at this point to maintain backwards compatibility with API 13 and below, use both `android:requiresFadingEdge="none"` and `android:fadingEdge="none"` together.

Comment: The accepted answer is out of date. This is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you targetSdkVersion >= 14 than there will be no fading edges.

```
android:requiresFadingEdge
```

can help you to get them back.

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)