# Remove FadingEdge on GridView. Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I need to remove fading edge from my gridview. I'm made a little research, currently below is what my gridview looks like, the problem is that nothing works. Is there any way to disable/remove/hide fading edge?

```
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/shop_grid_cart_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#C4C4C4"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="0px"
        android:numColumns="1"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        android:verticalSpacing="3dip"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="none"  
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"          
        tools:listitem="@layout/shop_cart_grid_item" />
```

OnCreateView:   `cartItems.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

android:overScrollMode="never"

And also the answers here :
[Is there a way to disable/edit the fading that a list view has at its edges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130461/is-there-a-way-to-disable-edit-the-fading-that-a-list-view-has-at-its-edges)