# How to hide the white colour after scroll drawer of attached screen shot

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, materialdrawer

I am using the library MaterialDrawer in my android application to create the drawer, but it shows some white after scrolling the drawer.

[image: screenshot showing the issue]

How may I hide this?

Answer (score 0):

To remove fading edges include this lines in your xml layout `android:fadingEdge="none"`

for more details [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130461/is-there-a-way-to-disable-edit-the-fading-that-a-list-view-has-at-its-edges)

Answer (score 0):

The shown issue is fixed in the latest version of the library.

If you can't update use the `Drawer` object to get the reference to the `ListView` with, `getListView()` you can then modify this property via

```
drawer.getListView().setFadingEdgeLength(0);
drawer.getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```